# Node MongoDb { err: 'connection to [127.0.0.1:27017] timed out' }

Tags: node.js, mongodb, localhost

I can connect to my mongo database from the command line by doing this:

```
$ mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/my_database
```

But when I try and connect with my node.js code I am getting back the error:

```
{ err: 'connection to [127.0.0.1:27017] timed out' }
```

Here is my code:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient;

var DB_NAME = 'my_database';
var connectionString = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/' + DB_NAME;


MongoClient.connect( connectionString, function(err, conn)
{
    console.log(err, conn);
});
```

I'm not finding anything to explain this error, and I don't understand why my code should be failing when I can connect from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here was the version of mongodb.
Version `1.3.23` has this error.
I upgraded mongo in my repo, thus :

```
$ npm uninstall mongodb --save
$ npm install mongodb --save
```

And that gave me version `2.2.11`, and this has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue by restarting `mongod` and then restarting the Node process.